# Apply time scheduler on MySql data type(DATETIME)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

How can we apply time scheduler on DATETIME(MySql) data type.
For example - Let's say time is given like '2020-01-20 11:01:00'and scheduler timing is 30 minutes starts from 00:00.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a CRON job with the setting 0 30 0 20 1 2020.